# REST API for file sync

Tags: library, file-synchronization, api

I'm beginning work on a project which has, as one component, the need to synchronize files from a server to a local HTML5 IndexedDB store for offline usage, then later, the option to push changes from the IndexedDB store back to the server.

But before I re-invent the wheel on something that should be a pretty straight-forward process, I'm hoping to find a well documented standard API (if not client and/or server libraries) to do most of the heavy lifting.

I would also like my project to maintain a bit of openness, so adhering to an open standard (even if I have to write both the client and server side code in my particular case) is a big win.

WebDAV is a clear candidate for this task, but tracks a lot of meta data (authorship info, etc) that isn't particularly relevant to me, and it adds a lot of HTTP verbs, which I would rather not deal with (to be more consistent with a modern understanding of RESTful), and it is just generally a heavier protocol than I need for my limited task.

Are there any alternative free standards for such an API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/), and the closely related JavaScript client [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/) have proven to be very nearly exactly what I was envisioning.

It doesn't use a purely REST-compliant API, but the details are cleanly enough hidden beneath the complete, and well-documented API, that in my case it doesn't matter.

PouchDB has a very active user and development community, and CouchDB is starting to get back into the swing of things, after a bit of a hiatus, apparently, with an upcoming release of 2.0.

Answer (score -1):

HTTP already has these features and is the point of REST.

Quoted from spec http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

GET

> The GET method means retrieve whatever information (in the form of an
>   entity) is identified by the Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to
>   a data-producing process, it is the produced data which shall be
>   returned as the entity in the response and not the source text of the
>   process, unless that text happens to be the output of the process.

PUT

> The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the
>   supplied Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to an already existing
>   resource, the enclosed entity SHOULD be considered as a modified
>   version of the one residing on the origin server. If the Request-URI
>   does not point to an existing resource, and that URI is capable of
>   being defined as a new resource by the requesting user agent, the
>   origin server can create the resource with that URI. If a new resource
>   is created, the origin server MUST inform the user agent via the 201
>   (Created) response. If an existing resource is modified, either the
>   200 (OK) or 204 (No Content) response codes SHOULD be sent to indicate
>   successful completion of the request. If the resource could not be
>   created or modified with the Request-URI, an appropriate error
>   response SHOULD be given that reflects the nature of the problem. The
>   recipient of the entity MUST NOT ignore any Content-* (e.g.
>   Content-Range) headers that it does not understand or implement and
>   MUST return a 501 (Not Implemented) response in such cases.

DELETE

> The DELETE method requests that the origin server delete the resource
>   identified by the Request-URI. This method MAY be overridden by human
>   intervention (or other means) on the origin server. The client cannot
>   be guaranteed that the operation has been carried out, even if the
>   status code returned from the origin server indicates that the action
>   has been completed successfully. However, the server SHOULD NOT
>   indicate success unless, at the time the response is given, it intends
>   to delete the resource or move it to an inaccessible location.

The point of REST is you implement them as needed to store/save/delete the content as needed from your back end store.

Storing inside IndexDB is fine but you will need some form of status I am not aware of a library which does this as it is basically very simple.  You may want to hold a transaction log table which you use to propogate back information.

(I believe phonegap doesn't support IndexDB it uses WebSQL but there is a poly fill to use IndexDB API into WebSQL available)

Comment: 4 verbs does not a file-sync API make.